# Unable to exit a Greenplum SQL script

Tags: greenplum

Is there any way in `psql` (Greenplum flavour) of exiting a script?

I have tried with `\q` and `\quit`, e.g.

```
\echo "Hello";
\q -- or \quit
```

but I get:

```
my_database> \i my_script.sql
psql:/home/josh/my_script.sql:2: invalid command \quit;
```

(and a similar result for `\q`)

Comment: `\q` works fine for `\i` input for me here, with real PostgreSQL 9.3. I'm guessing Greenplum's old version of the client doesn't support it.

Comment: What do you get for `psql --version`?